# MariaDB/MySQL : replacing an unicode character by another one doesn't work (0 rows affected)

Tags: mysql, unicode, mariadb

I'm trying  to replace every occurence of the unicode character ["MINUS SIGN" (U+2212)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2212/index.htm) by 'HYPHEN-MINUS' (U+002D) into a column.

I tried various flavours of UPDATE..REPLACE commands, like :

```
UPDATE assets 
SET 
    asset_tag = REPLACE(asset_tag,
        concat("%", unhex('e28892'), "%"),
        concat("%", unhex('2d'), "%"))
WHERE
    asset_tag like concat("%", unhex('e28892'), "%");
```

All yields to the same result :

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 412  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

The table's charset is `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

What am I doing wrong ? I'm using the command line client.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `'%'` in `REPLACE`. So just make your replace function like this: `REPLACE(assert_tag, unhex('e28892'), unhex('2d'))`

Comment: Thanks !! Query OK, 412 rows affected (0.36 sec)
Rows matched: 412  Changed: 412  Warnings: 0

Comment: `SHOW WARNINGS;` right after running the query.  The Warnings may be important.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - there was no warning here, was it ?

Comment: Was there any warnings??